# Скрипты, запускаемые из jupyter notebook через !, не принимают аргументы

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Я хотел использовать [`nbscan`](https://github.com/conery/nbscan) для поиска по свёрнутым Jupyter блокнотам, но при попытке запуска из ячейки через `!nbscan.py -a --lot --of --arguments` он выдавал только `No files to scan`. Я добавил `print(args)` и `print(sys.argv[1:])` в `main`. Но они показали, что ни один аргумент не передаётся. При этом у меня работают команды вида `!echo something` в блокноте и `py -3.8 nbscan.py --help` в консоли. Кто-нибудь знает из-за чего возникла такая проблема? Если что, то всё выше указанное стоит на винде.

Попытка загуглить проблему не дала результатов, не смог даже найти упоминания именно такой проблемы.

Comment: А если ещё питон ему указать: `!python nbscan.py -a --lot --of --arguments` Не помню только, надо питону самому флаги указывать или нет

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, это сработало, спасибо! Вы можете оставить это как ответ и я его отмечу решением. Правда тут возникла другая проблема. Скрипты у меня хранятся в PATH, поэтому их запуск напрямую не проблема, но когда это делается через `py` или `python`, то он смотрит только в текущей директории. `$Env:PATH` юпитером не распознаётся. Вы, случайно, не знаете, как можно было бы обратиться к переменным окружения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно указать ещё сам питон - ведь запускаться должен именно он и ему уже передаются аргументы в виде запускаемого скрипта и его параметров:

```
!python nbscan.py -a --lot --of --arguments
```

По поводу дополнительного вопроса о переменных окружения. Вот так можно добавить путь в `PATH` посредством временной питоновской переменной `path`:

```
path = %env PATH
path += ':/something'
%set_env PATH=$path
```